# Mac mini SMB File Sharing and Sleep Mode

Tags: network, macos, sleep-wake, mac-mini, smb

I've a Mac mini (Mid 2010, El Capitan 10.11.6) which acts as file server. I enabled file sharing (SMB).

The Mac goes to sleep mode after 10 minutes (as configured). If a PC client tries to connect to the share (of the Mac mini) it wakes up (as it should). But after the PC is shutdown and there is no user connected to over SMB the Mac mini never goes to sleep mode again. Why?

I've to restart the Mac mini and then it goes again to sleep mode. The Mac mini is connected over an ethernet cable to the network.

**Update**

Using the following command `pmset -g assertions` in terminal before a PC client has connected.

```
2019-01-05 15:06:26 +0100 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
```

And after the PC has connected and shut down.

```
   NetworkClientActive            1
```

Comment: Is the PC user manually dismounting the SMB share before being shutdown?

Comment: @IconDaemon no the PC user just logs off or shut down his PC. The share is connected to a network drive (for example P:).

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, I suggest you try dismounting the P: drive (with whatever command one uses in Windows) before the user logs off and/or shuts down the PC. Perhaps the logout/shutdown process doesn't adequately sever the client connection, leaving the Mac Mini end perpetually thinking its connected.

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried the command `net use * /delete /y` on the Win 10 PC. After that command the network drive to the Mac mini isn't connected anymore. But the Mac mini doesn't go to sleep. So no success.